# Tkinter canvas update circle blinking

Tags: python, tkinter, scipy

I'm trying to display a simple pendulum with python using tkinter. I'm resolving the differential equation with the scipy module and then I display the pendulum updating the angle every 10 ms but the circle representating the mass is blinking and I don't know if there is any way to fix that and if not, should I use a different module than tkinter?

```
import math
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import tkinter as tk




class Pendulum:
    def __init__(self, root, l1, m1, theta1, theta1_v = 0, tmax = 10, g = 9.81):
        #initialization of the screen
        self.root = root
        self.root.minsize(480,480)
        self.root.maxsize(480,480)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.root, width = 480, height = 480, bg ='white')
        self.canvas.pack()

        #initialization of the pendulum
        self.l1 =l1
        self.l1p = self.l1* 100
        self.m1 = m1
        self.theta1 = theta1
        self.theta1_v = theta1_v
        self.tmax = tmax
        self.g = g
        self.x0 = 240
        self.y0 = 50
        self.x1 = self.x0 + self.l1p * math.sin(self.theta1)
        self.y1  = self.y0 + self.l1p * math.cos(self.theta1)

        #initialization of the different time
        #to solve the differencial equation
        self.t = [k/100 for k in range(100*self.tmax)]

        #solving the differencial equation and saving the result
        self.theta_list = self.calc_theta()

        #Display the initial condition
        self.canvas.create_oval(self.x0-2,self.y0-2,self.x0+2,self.y0+2, fill = 'black')
        self.canvas.create_oval((self.x1-self.m1),(self.y1-self.m1),(self.x1+self.m1), (self.y1+self.m1), fill = 'black', tags = 'mass')
        self.canvas.create_line(self.x0,self.y0,self.x1,self.y1,fill = 'black', tags='line')

        #counter to keep track of the correct angle to display
        self.i = 0


    def f(self,y,t): #function of the differential equation
        return [y[1], -(self.g / self.l1) * math.sin(y[0])]

    def calc_theta(self): #resolving the differential equation
        return odeint(self.f,[self.theta1, self.theta1_v],self.t)

    def update(self): #updating the screen
        if self.i == 100* self.tmax -1:
            self.root.destroy
            return 

        self.theta1 = self.theta_list[self.i][0] #take the next angle

        #updating the pendulum
        self.x1 = self.x0 + self.l1p * math.sin(self.theta1)
        self.y1  = self.y0 + self.l1p * math.cos(self.theta1)
        self. i +=1

        #updating the screen
        self.canvas.delete('all')
        self.canvas.create_oval(self.x0-2,self.y0-2,self.x0+2,self.y0+2, fill = 'black')
        self.canvas.create_oval((self.x1-self.m1),(self.y1-self.m1),(self.x1+self.m1), self.y1+self.m1), fill = 'black', tags = 'mass')
        self.canvas.create_line(self.x0,self.y0,self.x1,self.y1,fill = 'black', tags='line')

        #call update every 10ms
        self.root.after(10,self.update)

window = tk.Tk()
p = Pendulum(window,1,10,math.pi/2, 0, 5) 
p.update()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You are missing a parenthasis here: `self.y1+self.m1),` so your code should be erroring out. Fixing that however I see nothing wrong with the pendulum swinging. I cannot reproduce the flashing you have mentioned.

Comment: There [are methods](https://web.archive.org/web/20190530082613id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/canvas-methods.html) to update existing `Canvas` widgets. If you use them instead of deleting everything and recreating them from scratch, the animation would likely be smoother.

Comment: @martineau I do not think that delete all is the culprit here. There is only 3 objects on the canvas. Something else is the problem for the OP. Sadly I cannot reproduce the problem for testing.

Comment: @martineau Do you mean the coords method ?

Comment: Kiyosuke: Yes that one.

Comment: @Mike-SMT Indeeed I change  the updating function with : 'self.canvas.coords('mass',(self.x1-self.m1),(self.y1-self.m1),(self.x1+self.m1),(self.y1+self.m1))
self.canvas.coords('line',self.x0,self.y0,self.x1,self.y1)' But It's keep blinking

Comment: @Mike-SMT: That may well be (I can't test). Regardless, when doing animation in `tkinter` it's generally a good idea to update existing widgets because the memory for deleted ones is not freed nor recycled — so you can eventually run out of memory.

Comment: @martineau I agree it is good practice. I didn't mean to imply otherwise. I just don't think it is the cause of the flickering.

Comment: You might have better luck using the `pygame` module which is more animation-oriented thank `tkinter`.

Comment: @Kiyosuke: Tell about your hardware and graphics power, which *Windows Manager*?. Try `self.canvas.update_idletasks()` just after `.delete('all')`.

Comment: @stovfl I have an i5 6th gen CPU and i think python use the intel graphic card but I have already used tkinter to do a snake game and i didn't have this issue

Comment: @stovfl There does appear to be a lot of post where `update_idletasks()` fixed the issue. However it does not seam to be clear as to why. Would you happen to have any insight on this? I thought tkinter was already updating idle tasks in the mainloop so it is unclear to me why `update_idletasks()` is helping in similar situations.

Comment: @Mike-SMT ***"a lot of post where `update_idletasks()` fixed the issue"***:  As long as the OP didn't confirm we don't know that. *`<opinion on>`* For me, ***"flickering*** issues are indicating a overloaded `.mainloop()`. A `.after(...` runs at fixed delay, while `event`'s generated in your callback are runing at `idle` state. If the callback generated `event`'s are not finished until the next `.after(...`, you reach a state where previous `event`'s overlapping. `update_idletasks()` gives the `.mainloop()` a extra timeslice. *`</opinion off>`*

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @martineau's comments. To proove his assumption, here is a sample code showing the animation of 3 bouncing circles, defined as `oval` objects on a `Canvas`. As you can see, by updating the oval coordinates, instead of deleting/recreating them, no flickeing can be observed:

```
from tkinter import *

def tick():
  for item in items:
    xa, ya, xb, yb = canvas.coords(item[0]) # get item coordinates
    vx, vy = item[1:3] # get item velocity
    xa, ya = xa + vx, ya + vy # edit item coordinates by adding velocity
    xb, yb = xb + vx, yb + vy
    if xa < 0 or xb > width:  vx = -vx # horizontal bounce (reverse vx)
    if ya < 0 or yb > height: vy = -vy # vertical bounce (reverse vy)
    canvas.coords(item[0], xa, ya, xb, yb) # update position
    item[1:3] = vx, vy # update velocity
  win.after(10, tick) # recursive call of 'tick' after 10ms

win = Tk()
width, height = 640, 480
items, colors = [], ('#F00','#0F0','#00F','#000')

canvas = Canvas(win, width=width, height=height, relief=SOLID, border=5)
canvas.pack()

for n in range(3):
    # define dimension, position and velocity for each item
    dim, dx, dy = min(width,height)/8, width/4, height/4
    x, y, vx, vy = dx + n*dx, dy + n*dy, 3-n, n+1
    items.append([canvas.create_oval(x-dim, y-dim, x+dim, y+dim,
        width=5, outline=colors[3], fill=colors[n]), vx, vy])

win.after(1000, tick) # start animation after 1000ms
win.mainloop()
```

That said, I have to agree that `tkinter` is not intended for doing super-fast animations...

Comment: So i should try pygame instead ?

Comment: @Kiyosuke : do you see any flickering when running the code I provided on your device? If yes, it means that your device may lack of computing power. If not, it means that your modified code does not solve all the problem. Could you edit your OP and show your modified code?

Comment: @sciroccorics You could be less blunt. It would go a long way here on SO. You could have done without the "No, ure are wrong. " part.

Comment: @sciroccorics No the code run smoothly. You can find the modified code here : https://github.com/Code-Kiyosuke/Pendulum/blob/master/Pendulum.py

Comment: @Mike-SMT : Sorry I didn't meant to be blunt. I am French, and the French equivalent to "you are wrong" ("vous faites erreur") is  extremely polite. I've checked Google translate after your comment and it happens that "vous faites erreur" is actually translated by "you are wrong". So what should I have written?

Comment: @sciroccorics that is interesting to know. I am in the US and "you are wrong" can come off as aggressive/rude here and other English speaking countries that I have encountered over the years. I would have just left out that part and the rest of what you said was good. I was not saying that it was terrible or anything just that it can come off as rude here and some of the SO community can get offended easily.

Comment: @Mike-SMT : Thanks for the clarification.So the lesson of the day is "I should not always translate straightforwardly in my mind before writting English" ;-)

Comment: @sciroccorics it is something to consider. Also it would be a good lesson to not always assume just because something was written in English that the users 1st language was English. :D We all get to learn something today lol.